# reduce price by on AWS (EC2 and spot instances)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scaling

I have a queue of jobs and running AWS EC2 instances which process the jobs. We have an AutoScaling groups for each c4.* instance type in spot and on-demand version.

Each instance has power which is a number equal to number of instances CPUs. (for example c4.large has power=2 since it has 2 CPUs).

The the exact power we need is simply calculated from the number of jobs in the queue.

I would like to implement an algorithm which would periodically check the number of jobs in the queue and change the desired value of the particular AutoScaling groups by AWS SDK to save as much money as possible and maintain the total power of instances to keep jobs processed.

Especially:

1. I prefer spot instances to on-demand since they are cheaper
2. EC2 instances are charged per hour, we would like to turn off the instance only at the very last minute of its 1hour uptime.
3. We would like to replace on-demand instance by spot instances when possible. So, at 55min increase spot-group, at 58 check the new spot instance is running and if yes, decrease on-demand-group.
4. We would like to replace spot instances by on-demand if the bid would be too high. Just turn off the on-demand one and turn on the spot one.

Seems the problem is really difficult to handle. Anybody have any experience or a similar solution implemented?

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly write your own code to do this, effectively telling your Auto Scaling groups when to add/remove instances.

Also, please note that a good strategy for lowering costs with Spot Instances is to appreciate that **the price for a spot instance varies by**:

- Region
- Availability Zone
- Instance Type

So, if the spot price for a `c4.xlarge` goes up in one AZ, it might still be the same cost in another AZ. Also, the price of a `c4.2xlarge` might then be lower than a `c4.xlarge`, with twice the power.

Therefore, you should aim to **diversity** your spot instances across multiple AZs and multiple instance types. This means that spot price changes will impact only a small portion of your fleet rather than all at once.

You could use [Spot Fleet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html) to assist with this, or even third-party products such as [SpotInst](https://spotinst.com/).

It's also worth looking at [AWS Batch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html) (not currently available in every region), which is designed to intelligently provide capacity for batch jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Autoscaling groups allow you to use alarms and metrics that are defined outside of the autoscaling group.

If you are using SNS, you should be able to set up an alarm on your SNS queue and use that to scale up and scale down your scaling group.

If you are using a custom queue system, you can push metrics to cloudwatch to create a similar alarm.

You can determine how often scaling actions do occur, but it may be difficult to get the run time to exactly one hour.

Comment: I tried alarms and the result is, alarms are slow. It takes alarm up to 5 minutes to start a new instance. Also, how would you handle spot instances? The number of EC2 instances we run should be approx. QueueSize / C, where C is a constant. You can't do that with alarms.